# Transforming UV vertices using numeric values in Blender 2.7

Tags: transforms, uv-image-editor

How can I perform Move, Rotate and Scale transformations on UV vertices using precise numeric values?  Is there an add-on I can use?

When I transform most types of spatial elements in Blender, the Tools panel displays a panel of options for that transformation, particularly a list of numeric input fields.

When I transform UV vertices in the UV/Image Editor, no such options panel appears in the UV/Image Editor Tools panel, but an options panel does appear in the 3D view Tools panel.  When I adjust the numeric values in that options panel the mesh gets transformed instead of the UV vertices.

When I transform UV vertices in the UV/Image Editor, copy the logged python code used to perform that operation, and run that code in the python console, the mesh is transformed instead of the UVs.

It seems that Blender's UV transform UI is simply a half-hijack of the regular transformation workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you hit N, you open a panel which has a field by which you can move vertices precisely.  Blender also allows you to perform mathematical equations in these fields.
[image]

As for rotating and scaling, there is no field to type into, but you are able to do it in another way.  After hitting "r" to rotate, you can simply type in the number of degrees to rotate it by.  This also works for scaling, and this can even be applied in the 3D view.

Also, if you open the tool panel (t), you will find two buttons for quickly rotating in 90 degrees, shown by arrows on the picture below.  You can also use the snapping tool, which is circled below.  You can turn it on and off by clicking the magnet button which I circled, or by holding down ctrl.  This will rotate it by 5 degree increments, or scale it by increments.  Blender even shows by how much you are moving/scaling/rotating in numbers where I have drawn the square below.  It only shows it while you are performing the action, however.

[image: rotate/scale]

Hope this helps you.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, that is helpful to know and will work for Move operations, though in this case I am also looking for precisely setting the properties for other transform operations such as Rotate and Scale.

Comment: I edited the question to include that clarification.

Comment: You are able to precisely rotate and scale.  After hitting "r" or "s" to rotate or scale, you can then type in the number of degrees you want to rotate/scale by.  You can do this both in the positive and negative direction.  All you do to rotate in the negative direction is add a "-" sign.